# How Do I Set Up Authentication with Client Certifcates on WebSphere 7

Tags: browser, ssl, webserver, ssl-certificate, websphere

Can someone point me to documentation on setting up authentication using client certificates on Websphere 7?  What does WAS send to the browser so the browser knows to send a certificate to the server?  How does the browser know when it should send a certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Some long explanation (though specific for the Community Edition) can be found here, at developerWorks:

[IBM developerWorks: Client authentication using digital certificates in WebSphere Application Server Community Edition](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0606_chillakuru/0606_chillakuru.html)

The more specific information for WebSphere Application Server 7 (not so lengthy) can be found here:

[WAS 7.0 Information Center: Secure Sockets Layer client authentication](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/csec_ssl_clientauth.html)